# How would you remove the last part of a string contained in brackets in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a flat file that is imported into my php script.

Example of output:

```
Forks [Office]
Glue [Crafts]
Jacks [Toy]
```

I would like to remove the text in between the brackets, as well as the brackets themselves at the end of each line.

I was thinking "rtrim" but the characters lengths differ.

Maybe "explode"?

Comment: A regex would seem like the easiest solution.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @BenM `rtrim`, and `explode`, it seems. =p

Answer (score 3):

Use `preg_replace`

```
$newValue = trim(preg_replace('/\\[([^\\]]*?)\\]/','',$oldValue));
```

An explanation of how this regex works:

`[]` matches a range of characters, so `[^\]]` matches any character that **isn't** a closing square bracket (you have to use a backslash to escape the character since `[]` is a regex operator.) The `*` operator modifies the range to match any of these characters 0 or more times, and the `?` makes it non-greedy (stops when the first `]` is found). Put this all inside of a group `()` and then you have what you're looking for. You have to escape your backslashes further so it works inside of a string for `preg_replace`

I find that this [Regex Cheat Sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) is great for quick reference, but you should read some articles about how to use regular expressions first. It's the most powerful tool any programmer could have.

Comment: You could add `\s+` before the brackets to remove the extra spaces

Comment: `trim()` would be better in case there is whitespace anywhere in the final product. Edited for your suggestion

Answer (score 3):

loop trough each line and then:

```
$line = substr($line, 0, strrpos($line, '['));
```

regular expression would probably be better

edited from strpos to strrpos as suggested by Jessica

Comment: Just in case [ occurs earlier, I would use strrpos. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php - While a regex could do it, this is a much simpler solution that should work fine.